# Sendbird Video Chat is echoing

Tags: video, echo, chat, sendbird

We are using Sendbird Video Chat API on our Magento 2 website but we are facing issues like whenever we start the chat, its echoing.

https://sendbird.com/

We have tried without headsets and from different systems but still having the same issue.

Can anyone suggest me that how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the PM for SendBird Calls, and my team and I are here to get you up and running properly.  Can you share more about how you have implemented the SDK?  Is it simply an echo you are hearing?  Or are you getting microphone feedback?  There are a number of possible issues going on, so the more you can describe, the better we can diagnose.

Comment: Hi @KC Kern, I'm getting the echo when I talk via video chat. Its happening with and without earphones. Please guide

Comment: @Siva, if you are implementing in Javascript, you will note that there are two `<video/>` elements, one for local, and one for remote.  In order to prevent the local audio from playing back in the element (echoing) you must include the attribute `muted`.  Example: `<video id="viewer_local" autoPlay muted></video>`

 Make sure you only do this on the local element, because if you do it on the remote one also, you will not be able to hear the person you are calling.